# Why does this numeric equation using a cosine produce a different result between a console application and windows application?

Tags: c#, math, .net-core, floating-point, visual-studio-2019

I write a mathematical function to be benchmark function in my optimization algorithm.

```
public static double SolomonFunction(double[] x)
    {
        double f;
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += x[i] * x[i];
        }

        f = 1 - Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * Math.Sqrt(sum)) + 0.1 * Math.Sqrt(sum);
        return f;
    }
```

but it has different result in console application and windows application when the input is `SolomonFunction(new double[] { -4.74641638144941E+151, -6.49440696607247E+153, -1.0998592442531E+153, 3.58027097738642E+149, 6.28490996716059E+152 })`

in console application the result is `6,616968044816507E+152`
in windows application the result is `-4,09139395927863E+154`

Is there something different that I need to do in a windows application that I don't need to do in a console application? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Comment: Have you recompiled your application? What value do you expect? https://dotnetfiddle.net/BNZXwk shows `-4.09139395927863E+154` as result.

Comment: yes I have, but the result still same. it should be the value from my console application I think.

Comment: Difference is between Net.Core and Net Framework

Comment: @Steve oh man you're right. I make new windows application with Net.Core and the result is same now

Comment: why it have different result ?

Comment: I am aware of [this difference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/floating-point-parsing-and-formatting-improvements-in-net-core-3-0/) between Net.Framework and Net.Core, however, the difference is very big. even calling BitConverter.GetBytes and checking the output between the two versions gives a very different output.

Comment: is it possible to change my old windows application from .Net Framewok to .Net core ? because it take too much time if I should build the UI from 0 again

Comment: Is this a Winforms or WPF Application? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview

Comment: @KlausGütter Winforms

Comment: OK, this is above my knowledge level. We need a guy well versed in the floating point field.

Comment: The result computed in the “windows application”, 6.6169…•10^152, has been faithfully calculated, meaning the elementary floating-point arithmetic has been performed in conformance to IEEE-754 with the binary64 (“double precision”) format or nearly so and the cosine is at least close. However, the argument passed to `Math.Cos` is about 4.16•10^154. At that scale, the slightest change in the argument, to the next nearest representable value, is about 5.95•10^138, so it goes around the circle 9.48•10^137 times…

Comment: I believe the changes arise from this: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/4847

Comment: … In other words, the calculation of the cosine is entirely meaningless. Each and every error in the calculations leading up to the value passed to the cosine swamps the period of the cosine so many times it is utterly impossible to tell where in the period the argument ought to actually be. On the other hand, this is also irrelevant to the final answer, as `1 - Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * Math.Sqrt(sum))` produces some result in [0, 2], and that is lost when `0.1 * Math.Sqrt(sum)` is added. The latter is about 6.6169•10^152, so it is entirely responsible for the result.

Comment: I do not see any way to obtain −4.09•10^154 as a result except if the `Math.Cos` function broke and returned some absurd result. The calculation of `sum` should yield about 4.37•10^307, and then its square root is about 6.62•10^153. In no situation should its square root be negative. Maybe the `FCOS` instruction produces absurd values when operands are outside of its supported range (−2^63 to +2^63)? To test this, print the value of `Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * Math.Sqrt(sum))`.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/8528

Comment: Here is evidence in favor of the broken cosine: If we change the calculation from `1 - Math.Cos(2 * Math.PI * Math.Sqrt(sum)) + 0.1 * Math.Sqrt(sum)` to `1 - (2 * Math.PI * Math.Sqrt(sum)) + 0.1 * Math.Sqrt(sum)`, that is, just replace the cosine by its argument, we get the other reported result, −4.09139…*10^154. In other words, if `Math.Cos` fails for large arguments and simply returns the argument, we get the observed result.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This seems stuff for a great answer.

Comment: @Steve: Writing it up now…

Comment: Yes, `Math.Cos(4.15756363972679E+154)` returns `4.15756363972679E+154` for net48 and `-0.6170167853734676` for net6.0

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, the broken cosine function is solved by change .Net Framework to .Net Core.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the platform that produces “-4,09139395927863E+154”, the `Math.Cos` routine is broken. It apparently uses a processor instruction that does not support operands outside [−2<sup>−63</sup>, +2<sup>−63</sup>].

Since I do not use C#, here is a C program that reproduces the correct behavior:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static double SolomonFunction(size_t length, double *x)
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        sum += x[i] * x[i];

    return 1 - cos(2 * M_PI * sqrt(sum)) + 0.1 * sqrt(sum);
}


#define NumberOf(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof *(a))


int main(void)
{
    double x[] = { -4.74641638144941E+151, -6.49440696607247E+153, -1.0998592442531E+153, 3.58027097738642E+149, 6.28490996716059E+152 };
    printf("%.16g\n", SolomonFunction(NumberOf(x), x));
}
```

When run with Apple Clang 11 on macOS 10.14.6, this produces “6.616968044816507e+152”. Looking at the calculations, we can see that `sum` must be huge and the result should be entirely dominated by `0.1 * Math.Sqrt(sum)`. Since the range of cosine on real numbers in [−1, +1], the `1 - Math.Cos(…)` part of the formula should have negligible effect, regardless of the argument to `Math.Cos`. So this seems like a reasonable result.

Considering the other result, “-4,09139395927863E+154”, we see it is impossible for the formula to produce a negative result when correctly calculated. `1 - Math.Cos(…)` should be in [0, 2], and `0.1 * Math.Sqrt(sum)` should never be negative, so their sum should be non-negative.

This incorrect result is entirely explained by a defective `Math.Cos`. Suppose, when the argument is huge, `Math.Cos` returns its argument instead of its cosine. We can reproduce this with the C code above b y using `return 1 - (2 * M_PI * sqrt(sum)) + 0.1 * sqrt(sum);`, where `cos` has been removed, leaving just its argument. Running this produces the output “-4.091393959278625e+154”, matching the reported output (with rounding to a different number of digits), confirming the hypothesis.

This is consistent with behavior of the `FCOS` instruction. Intel 64 and IA-32 Architecture Software Developer‘s Manual, combined volumes, December 2017, page 906, says, for `FCOS`:

> If the source operand is outside the acceptable range, the C2 flag in the FPU status word is set, and the value in register ST(0) remains unchanged.

Thus, when the cosine argument is out of the supported range (−2<sup>63</sup> to +2<sup>63</sup>), executing `FCOS` leaves the argument in the register that is also used for the result. Then `Math.Cos` apparently uses this value for the result.

Comment: Postpischill Thank you so much for your explanation. It make sense now, Math.Cos function in .Net Framework use the following rule like you said